# Hardware shopping: Can all M Key Slot work with NVMe?

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, nvme, m.2

I have a [NP500R5H-XD3BR](https://www.samsung.com/br/support/model/NP500R5H-XD3BR/) (Expert X50) Notebook from Samsung. 
It's the 2015 model, with I7 5500.

I didn't get this information from Samsung, however I know that it has a **Key M** slot for SSD M.2.

My question is:
**Knowing that I have a M.2 slot with key M, if I buy a NVMe, will it work?**

I want to buy a 1TB SSD M.2 but I do not want to spend a lot of money (around R$ 800 (Brazil)).
What would you suggest?

Comment: I can't read Portuguese, but there may be something on [https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1332710-ssd-m2-samsung-x50-np350xaa-xf3br-2018/](https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1332710-ssd-m2-samsung-x50-np350xaa-xf3br-2018/) that is useful to you. I looks to me like several versions of the laptop are discussed - *if* your one mentions NVMe in the UEFI then you could be in luck. But it might only be the np350xaa-xf3br version that has it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks. They are, basically, talking about the 2018~2019 version of this PC. This version accepts NVMe, even when the product specification doesn't say anything. Mine is an older version, 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to find in the [product specification](https://www.samsung.com/br/support/model/NP500R5H-XD3BR/) that an NVMe drive can be used with your PC. NVMe requires additional circuitry in its drive controller. Unless you can obtain the hardware manual or spec sheet for your laptop AND it says NVMe is supported, that's a firm NO.

Therefore, you are limited to SATA-II or SATA-III M.2 drives, which *are* available in terabyte sizes.  Some M.2 slots are for SATA-II, others will accept SATA-II and SATA-III.

Make sure that M.2 slot is not for an MMC card. I have two laptops with MMC only, and they will not accept the standard M.2 drive.

Also make sure the dimensions within the PC allow the length of the M.2 drive; those drives are found in multiple lengths, so make sure you buy what will fit.

Comment: Even having Key M, I can't use NVME with slower speed? (it is cheaper)
Can you suggest me any SATA III M.2 Card with 1TB?

Comment: @Filipi - Hardware recommendations are specifically out of scope here at Super User.  Your hardware also does not even appear to support NVMe SSDs.  Simplest way to confirm that is the case, is to determine, if your current SSD is SATA or NVMe as it appears your device comes with both a traditional mechanical HDD and a SSD

Comment: NVMe requires additional circuitry in its drive controller.  Unless you can obtain the hardware manual or spec sheet for your laptop AND it says NVMe is supported, that's a firm NO,

Comment: Ok. I am going to assume it doesn't supports. I was afraid of that hahahah

Comment: Anyway, Do you have any suggestion for me to buy?

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the Q&A site to ask that question.